# How to fetching content from an URL and parse json

Tags: android, json, android-parser

I have 2 TextViews in my layout with id's (matricula, nome) and i need get this values from this [json request](http://tcc-teste.aws.af.cm/api/alunos/1).

I have difficults in both make json request as in get values, here is an example how would i do in php and jquery:

PHP

```
$alunos = json_decode("let's pretend json data is here");

echo "Matricula: " . $alunos['Aluno']['matricula'];
echo "Nome: " . $alunos['Aluno']['nome'];
```

Jquery

```
var alunos = $.parseJSON("let's pretend json data is here");

console.log("Matricula: " + alunos.aluno.matricula);
console.log("Nome: " + alunos.aluno.nome);
```

To help:
Aluno = Student 
Matricula = Student id 
Nome = name

I read some answers here about parsing json but i admit it, its hard to understand.

Comment: You need to parse it via php or java ?

Comment: JAVA, php was just an example

Answer (score 1):

It is also easy in Java (I left out all error handling to focus on the main flow, please add that yourself):

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

...

private String readString(Reader r) throws IOException {
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    int len;
    while ((len = r.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        sb.append(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

...

// fetch the content from the URL
URL url = new URL("http://..."); // add URL here
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
String jsonString = readString(in);
in.close();
conn.disconnect();

// parse it and extract values
JSONObject student = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String id = student.getJSONObject("Aluno").getString("matricula");
String name = student.getJSONObject("Aluno").getString("nome");
```

For details please see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: what is "theJsonString" ?

Comment: The same as your `"let's pretend json data is here"`

Comment: I have edited the answer is it clearer now? The parsing is done when you create the JSONObject.

Comment: i understand, but you have to assume that i dont know how to extract "{Aluno: {"Matri..}}" from the url that i have...

Comment: So actually the question is not about parsing JSON but about fetching content from an URL? This is not clear at all from the question you posted.